# In generating a k-regular graph using igraph in R, is every k-regular graph unique and non-random?

Tags: r, igraph

I would like to generate a k-regular graph using `igraph` in `R`. A sample function I have going, which first obtains the game, then converts to an adjacency matrix is:

```
game <- sample_k_regular(no.of.nodes=3000, k=30)
game_adj <- as.matrix(as_adj(game))
```

It seems that there is no randomness in `sample_k_regular`, such that if we did another sampling, such as:

```
game2 <- sample_k_regular(no.of.nodes=3000, k=30)
game2_adj <- as.matrix(as_adj(game2))
```

and computed the difference:

```
sum(game2_adj-game_adj)
```

we get exactly 0.

Once we specify the number of nodes and the degree (number of neighbors) of each node, will it be exactly unique? (Meaning there is no effect from adding `set.seed()` on top of the function call?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There indeed is randomness. Let's take something more tractable:

```
game1 <- sample_k_regular(no.of.nodes = 5, k = 2)
game2 <- sample_k_regular(no.of.nodes = 5, k = 2)
game_adj1 <- as.matrix(as_adj(game1))
game_adj2 <- as.matrix(as_adj(game2))

game_adj1
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
# [1,]    0    0    0    1    1
# [2,]    0    0    1    1    0
# [3,]    0    1    0    0    1
# [4,]    1    1    0    0    0
# [5,]    1    0    1    0    0
game_adj2
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
# [1,]    0    0    1    0    1
# [2,]    0    0    1    1    0
# [3,]    1    1    0    0    0
# [4,]    0    1    0    0    1
# [5,]    1    0    0    1    0
game_adj1 - game_adj2
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
# [1,]    0    0   -1    1    0
# [2,]    0    0    0    0    0
# [3,]   -1    0    0    0    1
# [4,]    1    0    0    0   -1
# [5,]    0    0    1   -1    0
```

However, you are right that

```
sum(game_adj1 - game_adj2)
# [1] 0
```

But that is expected because `sum(game_adj1)` and `sum(game_adj2)` are `no.of.nodes * k` by construction.

Comment: @user321627, does it answer your questions?